# Not accepting words like whats up

Tags: java

Am trying to get my program to accept words like whats up, hows things but it isnt all its ttaking is words like hello, hi but isnt taking any words with spaces like {whats up} can someone shed some light as to what am doing wrong? My code has no errors is just am trying to get it to accepts words like whats up , hows you

```
    * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */

    package bot;

    import java.util.*;

    /**
     *
     * @autr kesha
     */
    public class tst {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);



        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
        // the ArrayList replaces your HashSet.
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();   
        ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();  
        Random r = new Random();

        list.add("Hello");
        list.add("Hi");
        list.add("How's you whats up");
        list.add("Hey");

        list1.add("Yuh mother");

        map.put("hi", list);
        map.put("whats up", list);
        map.put("hello", list);

        map.put("hoe", list1);


        System.out.println("enter Hi");
        String str = input.next().toLowerCase().trim();

        while(map.containsKey(str)){

        if (map.containsKey(str)) {
            ArrayList<String> tmpList = map.get(str); 

            int randomNumber = r.nextInt(tmpList.size()); 

            System.out.println(tmpList.get(randomNumber)); 

 System.out.println("enter Hi");

        str = input.next().toLowerCase().trim();
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what's wrong with your code? Any errors?

Comment: `input.next()` only returns the next word. So if there's multiple words, you're out of luck. Try using `nextLine()` instead.

Comment: Your code does not run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling [`Scanner.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()), which "Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner".

You want to call [`nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) instead, which takes a whole line of input.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that .next() cuts your string up to the white space.
try this..

```
String str = input.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim();
```